# XML Xpath with PHP, node, subnodes how to select correctly

Tags: php, xml, xpath, domxpath

Hi i have this type of XML type exactly. And i need to get information using PHP xpath. XML looks like:

```
<row>
<id>1</id>
<product>
    <prodRow>
        <PID>Aa</PID>
    </prodRow>
    <prodRow>
        <PID>Ab</PID>
    </prodRow>
</product>
</row>
<row>
<id>2</id>
<product>
    <prodRow>
        <PID>Ba</PID>
    </prodRow>
    <prodRow>
        <PID>Bb</PID>
    </prodRow>
</product>
</row>
<row>
<id>3</id>
<product>
    <prodRow>
        <PID>Ca</PID>
    </prodRow>
    <prodRow>
        <PID>Cb</PID>
    </prodRow>
</product>
</row>
```

PHP script:

```
    if(file_exists("band.xml"))
    {
   $DOM = new DOMDocument();
       $DOM->load("band.xml");
   $xpath = new DOMXPath($DOM);
   $row = $xpath->query("//row/id");
   $prodRowID = $xpath->query("//row/product/prodRow");

    foreach($row as $vID)
    {
    echo "<b>".$vID->nodeValue."</b><br /><br />";  

    foreach($prodRowID as $pID)
    {
                            $prodID = $pID->getElementsByTagName("PID");
            echo "<b>".$prodID->item(0)->nodeValue."</b><br /><br />";  
    }       

    }

      }
```

The answer i get and don't know how to do that, everytime the row is reached, the PID is printing from all rows:

```
1
Aa, Ab, Ba, Bb, Ca, Cb
2
Aa, Ab, Ba, Bb, Ca, Cb
3
Aa, Ab, Ba, Bb, Ca, Cb
```

The answer i need to get:

```
1
Aa, Ab
2
Ba, Bb
3
Ca, Cb
```

Thanks for answer this is my headache, don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select the `prodRow`s inside the first `foreach`, indicate the context node, and not use an absolute XPath:

```
foreach($row as $vID)
{
   echo "<b>".$vID->nodeValue."</b><br /><br />";  

   $prodRowID = $xpath->query("../product/prodRow", $vID);
   foreach($prodRowID as $pID)
   {
        echo "LIGA <b>".$pID->nodeValue."</b><br /><br />"; 
   }       
}
```

Comment: Thanks that helped very much, both answers were right :) You are the best. you helped me so far a lot JLRishe.

Answer (score 0):

Your inner `foreach` does always the same because it does not refer in any way to your outer `foreach`. What you want to do is iterating over all `//row` nodes, then query `id` and `product/prodRow` *from there* with the context parameter of [`DOMXpath::query()`](http://php.net/domxpath.query).

Comment: Thanks i will keep that in mind, you were right about this, i always refer in //row nodes, and JLRishe showed below how don't do that. Thanks both of you. Cheers !